# SSH Fails, /bin/bash: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, user-management, chroot

I have a user who is jailed.

sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match user matt
     ChrootDirectory %h
     X11Forwarding no
     AllowTcpForwarding no
```

passwd:

```
matt:x:1001:5006:Matt Ryan,,,:/home/matt:/home/matt/bin/bash
```

This works perfectly for sftp. The user is limited to his home folder, and whatever mounts are there.

But, I'd like to also give this use shell access. This is what happens when they attempt to log in:

```
$ ssh matt@server.com
Linux devnode 2.6.38-linode31 #1 SMP Mon Mar 21 21:22:33 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS

Welcome to Ubuntu!
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Thu Mar 31 13:04:29 2011 from abc.nyc.res.rr.com
/home/matt/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Connection to server.com closed.
```

Via fstab, the bin folder is mounted to the home directory and is present.

Why am I getting this error.. and how can I solve this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `chroot`, the named directory becomes `/`.  The correct shell path inside the `chroot` is then `/bin/bash`, not `/home/matt/bin/bash`.

You will also need to make sure there's enough other stuff inside the `chroot` for the system to work. You can test this with `sudo chroot /home/matt /bin/bash` and see what works and what doesn't; at the very least, you will probably want a dummy `/etc`, a `bind` mount of `/proc`, and much of `/lib` inside the `chroot`.

Comment: @geekosaur, thanks a lot... i just mounted the entire `/proc` and `/lib` folders to his home to test and it was successful. another question though, are bind mounts costly in anyway?

Comment: Bind mounts are essentially free.

Comment: great. one more for bonus: how can i enable color support for this user's shell

Comment: GNU `ls` wants some setup done by scripts in `/etc/profile.d`.  Some programs may also want to see `/usr/share/terminfo/*/*`.

Comment: seriously, thanks for you help. i'm having trouble bind mounting the /usr/bin here though. is there a better way to enable access to that?

Comment: If it's on the same filesystem then you can use `cp -lr /usr/bin /home/matt/usr/bin`; that also lets you remove anything you don't want to be available.

Comment: if new packages are added to /usr/bin will that require me to run this command again?

Comment: Yes.  You need the bind mount to get a direct image of it.  What's the error with the bind mount?

Comment: `mount point /home/matt/usr/bin does not exist`

Comment: Well, yes, you need to create a directory for the mount to bind to.  It doesn't need to have anything in it (in fact, better if it's empty as anything in it would be inaccessible after the bind mount).