# Configuring SFTP in ubuntu 18.04, error "/bin/bash No such file or directory" or "Unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server"

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, sftp, ubuntu-18.04

I'm configuring SFTP in ubuntu 18.04 following this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-18-04)
But when I try to connect from a FileZilla I get this error "Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server"
And when I try to connect from terminal I get this error "/bin/bash: No such file or directory"

**this is my "sshd_config":**

```
Match User my-user
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /var/www 
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

If I comment #ChrootDirectory, everything works like a charm, ... well no like a charm because then I have access to every file in ubuntu, which is not good for security reasons

**File permission for "www" folder**
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Aug 27 11:57 www

**File permission for "www/webapi"**
drwxr-xr-x 2 file-upload file-upload 4096 Aug 29 09:00 webapi

this is not working for me:
[SSH Fails, /bin/bash: No such file or directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/254233/ssh-fails-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory)

Any idea what am I missing ??? 
Thank you !!!

Comment: for a chroot to work you normally need the binary(s), + possible libs inside the chroot if you want to execute command within the chrooted environment.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution hope it helps someone else

open sshd_config file with sudo privileges
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server <- comment this
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp   <- add this line
```

Then apply a restart:
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd.service