# Could not able to connect to SSH after upgrade the Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-20.04

Error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1luQ.png)

SSH/SFTP :  /bin/bash no such a file or directory

I have server hosted on digital ocean, I have upgrade the Linux to version 20.0, everything works fine, even my website is also running fine but I couldn't able to access via SSH.

It was working absolutely fine before upgrade.

Attached the screen to understand more.

Comment: Can you get a shell via Digital Ocean console? If you are getting the same error, then somehow your `bash` software are missing. You have to boot some sort of rescue and reinstall it.

Comment: @NStorm yes, I can get a shell via Digital Ocean.

Comment: Does it works? Can you run `which bash && echo $SHELL` from it (and post it's output here)?

Comment: I run the command and its shows me result  /bin/bash for both.

Comment: Take a look at your sshd_config, can this https://serverfault.com/questions/254233/ssh-fails-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory be your case what you have chrooted environment under ssh?

Comment: I tried this but when i run command chroot its again throw me the same error. really I hang up , I am not than much familiar with Linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129360/discussion-between-nstorm-and-rws-piyush).